# Same java script executing multiple times on a web page in a browser

Tags: javascript, performance

What are the scenarios for a webpage to execute same java script multiple times? YSlow states duplicate java script execution should be avoided as it has performance implications but what about running same JS for creating multiple frames on a page. Is this a valid scenario? Please let me know if there are any valid scenarios where you need to have multiple duplicate JS execute in the browser?

Regards,
Xhings

Comment: There are many valid scenarios for JavaScript being run repeatedly, e.g. an animation or game loop. It really depends on the scenario. There could be script being run repeatedly incorrectly, if, for instance, an event handler is bound too many times to an event, or accidental recursion using while loops instead of an if construct. Do you have a specific problem to solve? At the moment, this is far too broad a question for SO. You should post the code that isn't working at the moment so that others can ascertain if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different scenarios. One of the most popular is ReactJS applications. JS code of your "view" can be executed multiple times on every change of your data. 
You may think about view as a pure function 
`fun(data) -> html`
React will be executing this function again and again on every data change.

Another interesting example can be a performance optimization. You can help the JIT to produce more specialized code if you use a specific function instead of generic. You can read about monomorphic/megamorphic calls [here](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html).